# C# Resource Value Changed With Button

Tags: c#, button, resources, uwp

I have a simple UWP application a simple calculator. So I set all the properties of the buttons through a style like this.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CalculatorButtons">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AntiqueWhite" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

I want to make a button that will change the Value of the Background property inside the Style i have made. My button code starts like this

```
private void ColorChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I am new in this and I can't find a way to access it and change it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of search i found everything i needed here http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/01/walkthrough-dynamically-skinning-your.html  The idea is really simple. so from my style i removed the background setter and made its own resource like this. but in its own dictionary which i named Style.Blue.xaml since its the blue color i did it for all my colors like Jerry Nixon said.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonColor" Color="Blue" />
```

and i would access it in my button with this line

```
Background="{StaticResource ButtonColor}"
```

After that i created this in MainPage.xaml.cs where my buttons are.

```
void ChangeTheme(Uri source)
    {   // Recreated my Merged dictinaries at the app.xaml

        var _Custom = new ResourceDictionary { Source = source };
        var _Main = new ResourceDictionary { MergedDictionaries = { _Custom } };
        App.Current.Resources = _Main;


        // This is needed to basiclly Refresh the page since we use Static Resources.
        // so we navigate forth and back to the whole frame.

        var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        _Frame.Navigate(_Frame.Content.GetType());
        _Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

then i added this code on every button and just changed the source depending on the color i wanted(if i wanted blue it was ->  Style.Blue.xaml for Red -> Style.Red.xaml) and ms-appx:/StyleColors/ is the path. i made a folder just for all of my Styles.

```
private void ColorChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeTheme(new Uri("ms-appx:/StyleColors/Style.Blue.xaml"));
        }
```

And now with a single line of code i can change the color of all my buttons or other type of data i need.

I hope it helps more people too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify style at runtime, the only way is to create new style and replace the old one.

```
private void ColorChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       var style = new Style(typeof(Button));

        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Stretch));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, 30.0));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1.0)));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black));

        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Orange));

        this.Resources["CalculatorButtons"] = style;
}
```

Please note, that you have to use DynamicResource in that case, e.g.:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=CalculatorButtons}" ...
```

Comment: okay i see but in a UWP i can't use DynamicResource that's what i am told from visual studio.
The post got changed to WPF sry about that, so my only option is to write a code that will change every button separately i guess since i can't use this code!